# Java 11 include jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac classes into project

Tags: java, compilation, java-11, javac

I need to work with `com.sun.tools.javac` classes that **are private** and are not visible neither during compile nor run time.

I use:

- **JDK 11.0.15**
- Maven build tool
- Intellij IDEA

My current state is that my imports are red-highlghited and compilation fails.

**My class I want to use sun tools inside** (sorry for the pic instead of code, my class is 2000+ lines length, for now I only care about availability of tools in my class):

[image]

**pom.xml**:

```
...

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>11</source>
                <target>11</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-sources</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I need to be able to have these classes available as I "type", during `mvn compile` and in runtime.

`com.sun` packages I'd like to have:

- com.sun.tools.javac.code
- com.sun.tools.javac.comp
- com.sun.tools.javac.file
- com.sun.tools.javac.main
- com.sun.tools.javac.model
- com.sun.tools.javac.parser
- com.sun.tools.javac.processing
- com.sun.tools.javac.tree
- com.sun.tools.javac.util

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make it work with the following compiler plugin configuration.

```
<compilerArgs>
                    <arg>--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.model=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>

                    <arg>--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.model=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                </compilerArgs>
```

And **other thing that broke my code** was `maven-javadoc-plugin` added to my plugins.

Answer (score 0):

The [Javadoc for package `com.sun.tools.javac`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/jdk.compiler/com/sun/tools/javac/package-summary.html) in Java 11 says:

> This package provides a legacy entry point for the *javac* tool. See the [`jdk.compiler`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/jdk.compiler/module-summary.html) module for details on replacement APIs.

Access the module `java.compiler`, package `javax.tools`, for the interface [`JavaCompiler`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) and class [`ToolProvider`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/tools/ToolProvider.html).

See the Javadoc for example code.

The `com.sun` package was never standard, never supported, and never intended for external use.

See [*JEP 403: Strongly Encapsulate JDK Internals*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/403).

Comment: Anyways there should be a workaround for this. Is there any "illegal" approauch to make this work?

Comment: Do you need more than the classes in [`com.sun.source.tree`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/jdk.compiler/com/sun/source/tree/package-summary.html) provide?

Comment: @Johannes Kuhn Updated the question with required packages of sun I need.